# Replace symbol in JSON with different array values

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have 2 files
**text.json** that contains

```
{
    "Files": [
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/*"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/*"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/*"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/*"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/*"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and **dlls.txt**

```
1.dll
2.dll
..
6.dll
```

I want to replace the symbol * with the necessary dll like this :

```
"Files": [
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/1.dll"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/2.dll"
        },
       .
       .
       .
        {
            "pattern": "/Something/Something/6.dll"
        }
    ]
}
```

So far my code replaces the symbol but only with the last array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **you're dealing with a structured data format - JSON - using a *dedicated parser* is always preferable** to performing purely *textual* processing based on *regexes*.

While using the dedicated [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) and [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) cmdlets to parse from and serialize back to JSON is *slower* than textual processing, it is much more *robust*.

```
# Read the DLL names from the text file into an array of strings.
$dlls = Get-Content dlls.txt

# Read the JSON file and parse it into an object.
$objFromJson = Get-Content -Raw text.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Loop over all elements of the array in the .Files property and
# update their .pattern property based on the corresponding DLL names.
$i = 0
$objFromJson.Files.ForEach({ 
  $_.pattern = $_.pattern -replace '(?<=/)\*$', $dlls[$i++] 
})

# Convert the updated object back to JSON; save to a file as needed.
$objFromJson | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Previously I tried to convert from json, but I couldn't get the raw data because of wrong syntax. Thank you, that solves everything :)

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped, @ИванЦанев; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Why not skip the `'C:\Users\itsan\Desktop\text.json'` file alltogether and simply create a new JSON from the dll filenames you have in `'C:\Users\itsan\Desktop\dlls.txt'` ?

```
$dlls = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\itsan\Desktop\dlls.txt'

$result = [PsCustomObject]@{
    Files = foreach($file in $dlls) {
        "" | Select-Object @{Name = 'pattern'; Expression = {"/Something/Something/$file"}}
    }
}
$result | ConvertTo-Json
```

If you want that as new file, simply change the last line into

```
$result | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Users\itsan\Desktop\dll.json'
```

Output wil be like this:

```
{
    "Files":  [
                  {
                      "pattern":  "/Something/Something/1.dll"
                  },
                  {
                      "pattern":  "/Something/Something/2.dll"
                  },
                  {
                      "pattern":  "/Something/Something/3.dll"
                  },
                  {
                      "pattern":  "/Something/Something/4.dll"
                  },
                  {
                      "pattern":  "/Something/Something/5.dll"
                  },
                  {
                      "pattern":  "/Something/Something/6.dll"
                  }
              ]
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have 80+ .dlls  and the pattern is different on every line.

Comment: @ИванЦанев Aha, you didn't make that clear in the question. In that case, accept [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62903317/9898643)